# Posso rodar dois projetos flutter com versões distintas na mesma máquina?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estou codando um app na versão Flutter 2.2.2, agora recebi uma tarefa para ajudar no app de um amigo, porém o app dele está na versão 2.1.3 e eu quero saber como eu posso rodar esses dois projetos na minha máquina que atualmente está instalada a versão 2.2.2 do Flutter sem dar nenhum conflito de versões.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, pode.
O SDK do Flutter nada mais é do que um monte de arquivos que você faz o download e coloca em uma pasta qualquer do SO. E o caminho desta pasta é definido no PATH apenas para facilitar a sua vida e conseguir rodar os comandos sem ter que navegar até a pasta onde ele está.

Levando isso em conta, você pode ter quantos SDKs você quiser, em diferentes pastas. E inclusive ir alterando o caminho deles diretamente em seu PATH.

Embora isso funcione, as pessoas geralmente utilizam o [fvm](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm)(Flutter Version Manager) que faz exatamente esta tarefa de baixar N SDKs em diferentes pastas, só que deixa de uma forma mais "simples" a mudança entre as diferentes versões. Além de alguns outros comandos que podem ser úteis.

A documentação do projeto é tudo que você precisa: https://fvm.app/

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar o Sidekick, o sidekick controla as versões e tem ambiente gráfico e permite rodar 2 ou mais versões do Flutter e definir a versão para o projeto específico.

https://github.com/leoafarias/sidekick